# URL error in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext

```
String temp1=(String)firstname.getText().toString(); 
String temp2=(String)lastname.getText().toString();
String urlreg="http://localhost/welcome.php?firstname="+temp1+"&lastname="+temp2;
```

Here firstname and lastname are the editText fields.

I am getting error as below.

LogCat error:

`09-11 22:11:09.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1204): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 22:11:09.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1204): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 54: http://localhost/welcome.php?firstname=ji&lastname=kij`

The code works fine if I modify it to

```
String urlreg="http://localhost/welcome.php?firstname="+temp1+"&lastname";
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: What is the value of temp1 and temp2 _exactly_? Please check it out in the debugger.

Comment: i'm declaring two strings temp1 and temp2... their values are equal to the values of edittext boxes of "firstname" and "lastname"

Comment: I mean whats is the value in the textboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using urlreg you need to url encode it to take out special characters using URLEncoder.encode().

Comment: Samir beat me to it.  Please vote up his answer and leave mine alone.

Comment: What exactly is being entered in the editText boxes?  Especially in the lastname box?  Can you please log that or look at it in the debugger?

Comment: i entered ji in firstname edittext box and kij edittext box in lastname...you can see it in LogCat... then i have a button on clicking it executes this code... Note that it is a runtime error..

Comment: I'm very surprised that encoding your URL did not solve the problem.  Perhaps you could log the encoded URL and let us see that looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do Httppost. It'll automatically encode your url.

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("var_name", value));

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.in/submit.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```